# Best practise to use OrmLiteBaseListActivity

Tags: android, listactivity, ormlite

what is the best practise to use the OrmLiteBaseListActivity?

Is there any way to keep the provided list view synced to the database? Or do I really always have to do this myself, using the add or remove methods of my array adapter (do I actually need one when using this activity?) whenever I change the database?

And which notifications should I send to keep the gui updated whenever the database changed? How about performance issues (a full "query all" for every change might not be a good idea)?

I could not find any information about that on the net...and in the ORMLite docs I couldn't find an answer to my questions...would be thankful for hints or links.

Answer (score 2):

I found this library recently

https://github.com/campnic/ormlite-android-extras

I haven't tried it yet, but it attempt to solve the whole list adapter using ORM problem.

Let us know how it went!

Comment: It's interesting, but it relies on API level 11 (and I'm developing for 10). Also there are some license issues which are not solved. But I guess it can serve as a basis for my own classes (it really seems I have to do sth myself there).

Comment: You can the Android compatibility package to get your app support higher APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use a ContentObserver with a ContentProvider to observe database changes instead of a third party ORM library. As far as I know the ContentObserver class can not be used with ORMs.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! This would solve the notification issue, but I really want to use the ORM lib...